# maven command to run specific test class got org.testng.TestNGException

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have **maven + testng** project as below:

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/config/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**testng.xml**

```
<test name="SendAuroraRequests_TEST">
    <parameter name="requestsToEnv" value="test" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.TrackerTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

**TrackerTest.java**

```
package com.test;
public class TrackerTest {

    private ITestContext context;

    @Parameters("requestsToEnv")
    @BeforeTest
    public void setInvocationCount(ITestContext context, String requestsToEnv){
        this.context = context;
        this.setInvocationCount(context, this, requestsToEnv);
    }
}
```

It works well when I try to run "**mvn test**" command, but when I try maven command to run specific test class like "**mvn test -Dtest=TrackerTest**", it throws exception like:

```
[ERROR] setInvocationCount(com.test.TrackerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.656 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.testng.TestNGException:

Parameter 'requestsToEnv' is required by BeforeTest on method setInvocationCount but has not been marked @Optional or defined

    [INFO]
    [INFO] Results:
    [INFO]
    [ERROR] Failures:
    [ERROR]   TrackerTest.setInvocationCount ? TestNG
    Parameter 'requestsToEnv' is re...
    [INFO]
    [ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  6.838 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-09T22:56:34+08:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project hfatest-tracker: There are test failures.
```

Looks run specific test class with maven command aren't try to get parameter from testng.xml, I also tried with command like "**mvn test -Dtest=TrackerTest -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/config/testng.xml**" but didn't work, how to make it works as expect?

**P.S:** I found here is related topic here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/testng-users/ccp_ewuNWlk/kmMXi0ycAwAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the two modes of execution. TestNG lets you run tests in two modes:

- Via a TestNG suite xml file
- Individual test classes by specifying the fully qualified class names of them.

You should try to use ONLY one of these modes and NOT mix them.

When you run your tests by passing in individual test classes via the `-Dtest` TestNG creates a command line suite, which would not have any parameters.

So you have two options:

1. When your tests involves parameters (`@Parameters` is used) then you stick to TestNG suite xml files.
2. If you still would like to run individual test classes via the `-Dtest` JVM argument then you can pass in the values of the parameters through JVM arguments [ so in your case it would be `mvn clean test -Dtest=TrackerTest -DrequestsToEnv= test` ]

This is possible because TestNG lets you pass values to `@Parameters` via JVM arguments.

For more details please refer to my blog post: https://rationaleemotions.com/building_dynamic_testng_suites/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's worked for me! [ mvn clean test -Dtest=TrackerTest -DrequestsToEnv=test ] it's what I want.