# How can I run a specific test from testng.xml file?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

hope someone help me with this question, thanks !

I have this in testng.xml

```
<suite name="Test Project" verbose="1" thread-count="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.tests.TestListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.tests.test1.LoginTest1"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.tests.test2.LoginTest2"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How can I run only the 'Test2'?

I tried `mvn test -Dtest=Test2` but it was not working, run both tests

Answer (score 0):

As explained in "[maven command to run specific test class got org.testng.TestNGException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57433307/6309)"

> You are mixing the two modes of execution. TestNG lets you run tests in two modes:
>
> - Via a TestNG suite xml file
> - Individual test classes by specifying the fully qualified class names of them.

In your case, you would need to use the class name of your `Test2`:

```
mvn test -Dtest=com.tests.test2.LoginTest2
```