# How can I run a specific test from testng.xml file which has multiple test?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, testng

Can't run directly mvn clean test -Dtest="com.dot.Management_Test". It has dependency in my application suite to pass suiteXml. Is there a way to run only the specific test in the SuiteXml by mentioning the SuiteXml in maven command "mvn clean test -DSuiteXml=school-mgmt.xml"

Tried this didn't help, mvn clean test -DSuiteXml=corex-cert-mgmt.xml -testnames subjectTest

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433307/maven-command-to-run-specific-test-class-got-org-testng-testngexception

Answer (score 0):

Not sure regarding the xml file you have but let's assume it as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="MyTestSuite">
    <test name="MyTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.TestClass1">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testMethod1" />
                    <include name="testMethod2" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="com.example.TestClass2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Use the following Maven command to run the specific tests defined in the XML file:

```
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=path/to/your/testng.xml -Dtest=testClass1#testMethod1,testClass1#testMethod2,testClass2
```

Replace path/to/your/testng.xml with the actual path to your TestNG XML file, and specify the test classes and methods you want to run after the -Dtest= option, separated by commas.

In the example above, it will run testMethod1 and testMethod2 from TestClass1 and the entire TestClass2.

Comment: Is there a way to specify running the test by the test name in the testng.xml--in this example `MyTest`?

Comment: mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml -Dtest=MyTest

Comment: Sorry my question was not specific enough; in this example there is only one test element so specifying the whole suite xml works. If there are multiple test elements in the xml is there a way to specify running just one of the tests?